# SQL Work Hours Only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a report, one of the requirements is that I find the turnaround time between two dates (columns) - I have done that using a DATEPART function, however, the hours are exaggerated, I have to find the time difference taking into consideration the following work hours:

1. Monday - Friday 08:00 to 17:00
2. Saturday 08:00 to 13:00
3. Closed on Sundays

I have attached the code below:

```
SELECT (au.firstname + ' ' + au.lastname) AS ClaimsHandler,
c.Id AS ClaimID,
c.ClaimNumber AS InsurerClaimNumber,
i.ContactName AS Insured,
c.BrokerName AS BrokerName,
lr.lastrouting AS DateTimeClaimRouted,
b.BranchName AS Outlet,
csh.CreateDate As DateClaimCompeleted,
-- I would like to exclude the work hours here
CAST( DATEPART(DAY, csh.CreateDate - c.CreateDate) - 1 AS nvarchar(100)) + ' days '
+ CAST( DATEPART(HOUR, csh.CreateDate - c.CreateDate) AS nvarchar(100)) + ' hrs '
+ CAST( DATEPART(MINUTE, csh.CreateDate - c.CreateDate) AS nvarchar(100)) + ' min '
+ CAST( DATEPART(SECOND, csh.CreateDate - c.CreateDate) AS nvarchar(100)) + ' sec' AS TurnaroundTime
FROM Claim c
INNER JOIN Branch b
on b.Id = c.BranchId
INNER JOIN Clients i
on i.ClaimId = c.Id
INNER JOIN InsuranceAccounts a
on a.Id = c.InsuranceAccountId and a.administratorid = 22
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] au on au.id = c.CallCentreAgent
INNER JOIN (
SELECT cliamid, MAX(createdate) AS lastrouting
FROM commentslogs
WHERE MESSAGE like 'Edit: Outlet Details%'
GROUP BY cliamid )
lr on lr.cliamid = c.id
INNER JOIN (
SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY claimid, ClaimStatusId ORDER BY createdate DESC) AS RN1 , *
FROM ClaimStatusHistories
WHERE ClaimStatusId = '4')
csh on csh.claimid = c.id and csh.RN1 = 1
```

Comment: Could you add schema information please? And which columns you'd like to use to filter the work time on.

Answer (score 1):

My initial suggestion would be to create a Time table with each row representing every minute spanning the range of dates for your claims. Each row would have a `bit/int` flag indicating if it should be summed as part of the total time worked on a claim. Minutes outside of normal work hours would have their flags set to zero so when they are `SUM`med, they won't be counted toward the total duration of the claim. You should be able to `JOIN` to the table and filter on Start and End dates, with an alternate being a user-defined function to encapsulate the logic. It won't address any flex-time scheduling for the claim processor but should give you a more accurate calculation as it'll discount the official off-hours for the company.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the `CAST( DATEPART(HOUR, csh.CreateDate - c.CreateDate)` gives me an error... I'm guessing you want to do the following:

```
DATEPART(HOUR, csh.CreateDate) - DATEPART(HOUR, c.CreateDate)
```

If I'm not understanding it properly, please add more info.